# Access JSON kind of data from a div?

Tags: javascript

So I have a div which displays the results from Microsoft emotion API such as:

```
anger: 0.28446418
contempt: 0.00341128884
disgust: 0.000332433876
fear: 0.009447911
happiness: 0.02609423
neutral: 0.6288482
sadness: 0.00180563633
surprise: 0.04559612
```

Here is the code for displaying the data:

```
 .done(function(data) {
        // Get face rectangle dimensions
        var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
        var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');
        var data1="";

        // Append to DOM
        for (var prop in faceRectangle) {
            data1 += "<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>";
        }
        faceRectangleList.html(data1);

        // Get emotion confidence scores
        var scores = data[0].scores;
        var scoresList = $('#scores');
        var data2="";
        // Append to DOM
        for(var prop in scores) {
            data2 += "<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>";
        }

        scoresList.html(data2);

    }).fail(function(err) {
        alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});



}

function make_graph(){


}
```

Now I need to plot a line from these scores.Can you tell me how to access each separate value of these scores in another function so that I can plot them as points in my graph?

Comment: You have the code right in your own question! Just loop over `data` and extract the values.

Comment: But the problem is that i need to access the values in another function,this is the API's result functtion.

Comment: Then please share a snippet that shows a bit more context.

Comment: Ypdated the snippet.

Comment: Can you please write code for that as i am not proficient in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `make_graph` from inside the `done` callback, passing it the data, like this.

```
.done(function(data) {
     // ... do what you already do
     make_graph(data);
}).fail(function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
});

function make_graph(data) {
    for (d in data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes!But how to access data inside the (d in data) loop as i'm storing the data in a string.Can you please help me with that as i'm new to coding.

Comment: `d` is not a string, it's an object, you use it like you use `data[0]` in your `done` function.

Answer (score 0):

From the given information, you can make a function like this

```
function drawLine(dataScores) {
    for (var d in dataScores) {
        // dataScores[d] will give you the score
        // rest of the relevent code
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
drawLine(scores);
```

Comment: Still i wont be able to access scores as it is a local variable when calling the function.

Comment: From where do you plan to call `make_graph`??

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good practice to write data in HTML DOM, then read it back.

But if You need this, try something like this

```
plotData = []
var scoresList = $('#scores')
scoresList.children('li').each(function(i) {
    data = i.thml()
    plotData.push(i.split(':').map(i => [i[0].trim(), parseFloat(i[1])]))
});

// here You have all data in plotData
// [['anger', 0.28446418], ...]
// Draw Your plotData here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it back from `div li`, here is a jquery function to covert html to jquery data object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataArr={};
    $("#scoresli" ).each(function( index ){
    data=$( this ).text().split(":");
    dataArr[data[0]]=data[1]
});
alert(JSON.stringify(dataArr));
});
//{"anger":" 0.28446418\n","contempt":" 0.00341128884"}
```

Comment: Your indentation has included your comment in the code block.